# if I cant use TLS in c# async programming what can I use?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

My current practice is to have a whole bunch of context information in TLS.

Reading MSDN article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx) about execution context capture it seems that

a) I cant depend on the continuation running on the same thread I started on

b) TLS is not cloned into the context of the continuation

So what can I do (apart from redesign the whole system to not use context bound implicitly to an execution path). Can I add custom data to the Execution context that will get captured?

I had a similar problem with TPL, in that case I wrote my own wrapper functions that cloned TLS into the TPL spawned workers

Comment: Check Stephen Cleary's ["Implicit Async Contex"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). Do you store any mutable data in TLS? Unlike with TLS, logical call context can be forked into multiple paths of execution (i.e. accessed from many threads), so mutable data can be an issue. I believe this applies to .NET 4.6 `AsyncLocal`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logical call context for that, which flows as a part of execution context: [`System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.LogicalSetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.logicalsetdata(v=vs.110).aspx)/[`LogicalGetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.logicalgetdata(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you store any mutable data in TLS, note that logical call context has a copy-on-write behavior and can be forked into multiple paths of execution (and thus accessed simultaneously from multiple threads, unlike with with TLS).

If you store an object, a reference to it gets copied (not a deep clone), so mutable data can be an issue. Any changes won't be propagated outside the scope of a particular copy of the logical call context.

If you really need to propagate logical call context data to the outer caller context, and you cannot use `Task.Result` for some reason, you still could use a mutable data object. You'd have to add it to the logical call context *before* before branching your execution flow with async methods (or entering new threads with an API like `Task.Run`, `Task.Factory.StartNew`, `Thread.Start`, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` etc). A word of caution: now multiple threads can possibly be racing to mutate the value concurrently.

It's easy to show by example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task TestAsync(string id, int delay)
        {
            // but we might not even have any asynchrony here
            // but making the method "async" is already enough
            // for the copy-on-write behavior to trigger

            await Task.Delay(delay).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // copy on write here
            CallContext.LogicalSetData("name1", "value1-modified-by-" + id); 
            var mutableData = (MutableData<string>)CallContext.LogicalGetData("name2");
            Console.WriteLine(CallContext.LogicalGetData("name1"));

            // racing to set mutableData.Data
            mutableData.Data = "value2-modified-by-" + id;
            Console.WriteLine(mutableData.Data);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallContext.LogicalSetData("name1", "value1");
            var mutableData = new MutableData<string> { Data = "value2" };

            CallContext.LogicalSetData("name2", mutableData);
            Console.WriteLine(CallContext.LogicalGetData("name1"));

            Task.WaitAll(TestAsync("A", 1000), TestAsync("B", 1000));

            Console.WriteLine(CallContext.LogicalGetData("name1"));
            Console.WriteLine(mutableData.Data);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class MutableData<T>
    {
        readonly object _lock = new Object();
        T _data = default(T);

        public T Data
        {
            get
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    return _data;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    _data = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check Stephen Cleary's ["Implicit Async Contex"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) for more details.

I believe the same propagation behavior applies to [.NET 4.6 `AsyncLocal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/asynclocal.cs,ef9ce034697240ba,references), too, even though it doesn't use `CallContext` internally.

Comment: does this work with TPL things like Parallel.ForEach

Comment: @pm100 yes. Again, it will be propagated into `ForEach` lambda, but any changes you make there won't be propagated back.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on .NET 4.6, you can use the [AsyncLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268.aspx) class.